# Dial knob in hotel bathroom

Tags: hotels

I saw this black dial knob in bathroom of multiple hotel rooms. It is numbered from 0-10.

Any idea what is the use of it?

[image]

It seems not a timer. It didn't tick back.
Changing it didn't -apparently- change anything.

Comment: Is the object with the coiled wire a hair dryer, and does the knob turn it on and, thus, a timer?

Comment: @Dorothy: Pretty sure that object is a telephone.

Comment: @NateEldredge Maybe OP could add some info, such as where he is, and whether there is a heat lamp in the ceiling.

Comment: It's just volume for background music, which was popular for awhile but usually just disconnected these days. Ask the staff!

Comment: Ideally it would go to 11.

Comment: If it’s defunct, you have a great oppertunity to add your own label as a gag. Say, “shower pH”.

Comment: Please stop turning that knob.  My cat keeps disappearing.

Comment: Is that a telephone in a bathroom? ...

Comment: @davidb I think the purpose of those telephones is if you suffer an accident, fall ill, or are unable to get up, you can summon medical help.

Answer (score 24):

Usually this controls the volume of an auxiliary speaker placed in the bathroom ceiling, connected to the room’s television. Presumably a number of people continue to listen to their television programmes as they go about their bathroom activities, although the utility of this innovation is rather lost on me.

It appears to do nothing if the television is not on.

The speaker may no longer be connected to anything if the television has been replaced since the hotel was last renovated.

Comment: I would guess a lot of business people like listening to the (stock) news in the morning

Comment: It's possible to receive radio broadcasts as well as television on many TV sets. It isn't unusual to listen to the radio in the bathroom.

Comment: It certainly beats most of the alternative sound sources in the bathroom.